# SQl comand works in Workbench but not from Java Program

Tags: mysql, java

I am working on a program that manages a database of client information.  I am currently stuck on a problem where the SQL statement created by my java program but get the error

> SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO Contact VALUES ("82136b4240d6ce4ea7d03e51469a393b","b","b","b","b","' at line 2
>   SQLState: 42000
>   VendorError: 1064

I would figure that the statement is incorrect, but if I run it in Workbench, it works exact.  The SQL statement I am using is as follows (merged into one string with \n for each line)

```
Begin;
INSERT INTO Contact VALUES ("82136b4240d6ce4ea7d03e51469a393b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ContactID=ContactID;
INSERT INTO Contact VALUES ("e9b3390206d8dfc5ffc9b09284c0bbde","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ContactID=ContactID;
INSERT INTO People (UID,LastName,FirstName,MiddleName,MadenName,AncestryID,23MeID,GedMatchID,ContactID,BusinessContactID,Notes,Deceased)Values ("a4057edb4d8205f3361c9ca350f67c1f","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","82136b4240d6ce4ea7d03e51469a393b","e9b3390206d8dfc5ffc9b09284c0bbde","",false) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE UID=UID;
COMMIT;
```

As a quick testing I have a command
    SELECT 1 + 1;
which seems to work just fine

It may help for some people to have the creation code for the tables.  The two relevant are as follow

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clients`.`Contact` (
  `ContactID` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Hashed number',
  `Address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Street` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `City` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `State` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  `Zipcode` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `HPhone` VARCHAR(10) NULL COMMENT 'HomePhone',
  `CPhone` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `Website` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `BuisnessName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `BuisnessWebsite` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  UNIQUE INDEX `ContactID_UNIQUE` (`ContactID` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ContactID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `clients`.`People`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `clients`.`People` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clients`.`People` (
  `UID` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `MiddleName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `MadenName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `AncestryID` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL COMMENT 'KitID',
  `23MeID` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL COMMENT 'KitID',
  `GedMatchID` VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
  `ContactID` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `BusinessContactID` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `Notes` BLOB NULL,
  `Deceased` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `23MeID_UNIQUE` (`23MeID` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `GedmatchID_UNIQUE` (`GedMatchID` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `UID_UNIQUE` (`UID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_People_Contact1_idx` (`ContactID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_People_Contact2_idx` (`BusinessContactID` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `AncestryID_UNIQUE` (`AncestryID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_People_Contact1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ContactID`)
    REFERENCES `clients`.`Contact` (`ContactID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_People_Contact2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`BusinessContactID`)
    REFERENCES `clients`.`Contact` (`ContactID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

As asked here is the java function I use to send the query

```
public int SQLAddTo(String FinalQuery, String userName, String password) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    txtStatus.setText("Processing");
    int intrs = 0;

    try {
        conn
                = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.249:3306/clients", userName, password);

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        intrs = stmt.executeUpdate(FinalQuery);
        txtStatus.setText("Done");

        // Now do something with the ResultSet ....
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        // handle any errors
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
        txtStatus.setText("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
// it is a good idea to release
        // resources in a finally{} block
        // in reverse-order of their creation
        // if they are no-longer needed

        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            } // ignore

            stmt = null;
        }
    }

    return intrs;
}
```

And the creation of the SQL statement and sent to the function

```
String queryContact = "INSERT INTO Contact (ContactID,Address,Street,City,State,Zipcode,Hphone,Cphone,Website,BuisnessName,BuisnessWebsite) "
            + "VALUES ('" + ContactH1 + "','" + txtAddress.getText() + "','" + txtStreet.getText() + "','" + txtCity.getText() + "','" + txtState.getText() + "','" + txtZip.getText() + "','"
            + txtHP.getText() + "','" + txtCP.getText() + "','" + txtWeb.getText() + "','" + txtBName.getText() + "','" + txtBW.getText() + "') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ContactID=ContactID;";

    String queryBContact = "INSERT INTO Contact (ContactID,Address,Street,City,State,Zipcode,Hphone,Cphone,Website,BuisnessName,BuisnessWebsite) "
            + "VALUES ('" + ContactH2 + "','" + txtAddress1.getText() + "','" + txtStreet1.getText() + "','" + txtCity1.getText() + "','" + txtState1.getText() + "','" + txtZip1.getText() + "','"
            + txtHP1.getText() + "','" + txtCP1.getText() + "','" + txtWeb1.getText() + "','" + txtBName1.getText() + "','" + txtBW1.getText() + "') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ContactID=ContactID;";

    String People = txtLN.getText() + txtFN.getText() + txtMN.getText() + txtMadN.getText() + txtAncID.getText() + txt23ID.getText()
            + txtGedID.getText() + ContactH1 + ContactH2 + txtNote.getText() + cbDead.isSelected();
    String PeopleH = MD5(People);

    //Final Query statement
    String FinalQuery = "Begin;\n\r" + queryContact + "\n\r" + queryBContact + "\n\r" + queryPeople + "\n\r"
            + queryDonations + "\n\r" + queryMembers + "\n\r" + queryAncAccess + "\n\r" + queryAncesty + "\n\r" + query23Access + "\n\r"
            + query23 + "\n\r" + queryGedAccess + "\n\r" + queryGed + "\n\rCOMMIT;";

    System.out.println(FinalQuery);

    //Execute SQL connection
    int Result = SQLAddTo(FinalQuery, "travis", "password");
```

Comment: How do you call it from java? You cannot just pass these lines to 'Statement.executeUpdate` . Each `insert` statement should be executed as a separate call to `Statement.executeUpdate` (and as far as I remember it should be no semicolon ). So you are getting connection object, set autoCommit to false, create a prepared statement object, execute inserts, and then commit (connection.commit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change java code to something like (for simplicity sake error handling and closing statements omitted)

```
 try {
    conn = ..... 
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    Statement s1 = conn.createStatement();
    s1.executeUpdate(/*first insert */);
    s1.executeUpdate(/*second insert */);
     // etc
    conn.commit();
  }
```

Side notes. 1) it's much better to use `PreparedStatement` if you executing the same query multiple times with different parameters.  2) make sure your catch block has `conn.rollback()` - you don't want to leave transaction open